# How to filter data using to_date function to filter YYYYMM from timestamp in sql query from python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, dataframe, to-date

I am getting an error while trying to filter data based on year month from timestamp column.

**INPUT**

```
 domain_name   INSERT_DATE        LOC
KNEU/TEREX   2019-05-08 12:05:13   AL
KNEU/TEREX   2019-05-16 11:45:49   BI
KNEU/TEREX   2019-05-21 11:45:49   MY
KNEU/TEREX   2014-09-11 11:45:49   SG
KNEU/TEREX   2014-09-11 11:45:49   IL
```

**MY code**

```
sql3 = """select * from location where domain_name = 'KNEU/TEREX'and to_date(INSERT_DATE,'YYYY-MM')=2019-05 """
dfotm4 = pd.read_sql_query(sql3, connection3)
```

**Error**

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from location where domain_name = 'KNEU/TEREX'and to_date(INSERT_DATE,'YYYY-MM')=2019-05 ': ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
domain_name   INSERT_DATE          LOC
KNEU/TEREX   2019-05-08 12:05:13   AL
KNEU/TEREX   2019-05-16 11:45:49   BI
KNEU/TEREX   2019-05-21 11:45:49   MY
```

What is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare year and month in `SQL`, we can make use of the [MONTH(expression)](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefmonthfunc.html) and [YEAR(expression)](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefyearfunc.html)

```
SELECT * FROM location WHERE domain_name = 'KNEU/TEREX' AND YEAR(INSERT_DATE) = 2019 AND MONTH(INSERT_DATE) = 5;
```

Error in your code is because you haven't wrapped `2019-05` in quotes, it should've been `'2019-05'`